# Postgresql - Copy row and set uid to new column

Tags: sql, postgresql, copy, duplicates

I'm working on a user management system and I need to copy a user to a "backup" table before the user will be deleted. How can I set the `id` to the new column `userid` while `id` on both tables are unique?

**users**

```
+----+------+-------------+--+
| id | lang |    email    |  |
+----+------+-------------+--+
| 20 | en   | test@ya.hoo |  |
+----+------+-------------+--+
```

**delusers**

```
+----+--------+------+-------------+
| id | userid | lang |    email    |
+----+--------+------+-------------+
|  1 |     20 | en   | test@ya.hoo |
+----+--------+------+-------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

First, if an user cannot be deleted twice, the `delusers.id` could be the `PRIMARY KEY` of `delusers` table, and you could use the value of the `id` of the user itself. There is no need of `id` **and** `userid` on `delusers` table.

Then, you can just `INSERT` on `delusers` and `DELETE` on `users` (inside the same transaction, of course):

```
BEGIN;
INSERT INTO delusers(id,lang,email)
SELECT id,lang,email FROM users WHERE id = 20;
DELETE FROM users WHERE id = 20;
COMMIT;
```

You could also do that on same command (using CTE):

```
WITH deleted AS (
    DELETE FROM users WHERE id = 20 RETURNING id, lang, email
)
INSERT INTO delusers(id,lang,email)
SELECT id,lang,email FROM deleted;
```

The last is good for some reasons:

1. You don't need to explicit open a transaction if this is all you are going to do (it would make no harm in opening it though);
2. You can delete lots of users at same time;
3. PostgreSQL does not need to find for the users at `users` table more than once (one for `SELECT` and other for `DELETE`). The same could be achieved with cursors though.

Comment: Thanks for the fast and de detailed answer MatheusOL, but i forgot to mention that the table has plenty columns. Is there a way to query the database without specifying all columns?